# Is the empty set closed under union?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\mathbf S$ be a set.

Then call $\mathbf S$ a $\cup$-stable set iff:

$\forall A, B \in \mathbf S: A \cup B \in \mathbf S$

Is $\varnothing$ a $\cup$-stable set?

Comment: Yes, vacuously.

Comment: Yes; the condition $\forall A,B \in S$ ... becomes vacuously true.

Comment: The formula $\forall A, B \in \mathbf S( A \cup B \in \mathbf S)$ is short for the formula $\forall A\forall B(A,B\in \mathbf S\implies A\cup B\in \mathbf S)$.

Comment: Does there exist any $A, B \in \mathbf S: A \cup B \not\in \mathbf S$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is vacuously true.  The condition $A,B\in\emptyset$ can never hold.

Comment: What's with the downvotes?